# Liquid Loop prints duplicates

Tags: loops, for-loop, liquid

I'm editing a "freshdesk knowledgebase" theme which uses (parts of?) liquid. I don't have a lot of experience.

The knowledgebase uses a structure of category: -> folder -> article

Here's the loop i'm having trouble with. While it outputs the list of available categories, it also prints a duplicate depending on how many articles are inside the folder.

```
<div class="category-list__items">
            {% for category in portal.solution_categories%}
                {% for folder in category.folders %}
            {% if folder.articles_count > 0 %} 
              <div  class="category-list-item">
                <a href="{{category.url}}" class="category-list-item__link">
                  <div class="category-list-item__content">
                    <h3 class="category-list-item__title">{{category.name}}({{ folder.articles_count }})</h3>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
             {% endif %}
           {% endfor %}
             {% endfor %}
             
          </div>
```

What I am wanting to output is a just a list of categories that have at least 1 article inside.

I'm getting:

- Fruits (2)
- Fruits (2)
- Vegetables (1)

When I just want:

- Fruits (2)
- Vegetables (1)

Comment: Seems the issue is with solution_categories data it must be having duplicated data, can you share what is in solution_categories?

Comment: The two categories are literally just Fruits and Vegetables. It prints fruits twice because there are two articles within a folder in the fruits category, and prints vegetables once, because there is one article inside a folder, inside the vegetables category. I can't figure out how to write the loop to say: If there's at least one article inside a folder in a category, print the category (once)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `{% break %}` to break the for loop conditionally.

So if you want to render a category only once when it finds a first folder with  `articles_count > 0` then break the loop and continue for next category like below.

```
<div class="category-list__items">
  {% for category in portal.solution_categories%}
    {% for folder in category.folders %}
      {% if folder.articles_count > 0 %} 
          <div  class="category-list-item">
            <a href="{{category.url}}" class="category-list-item__link">
              <div class="category-list-item__content">
                <h3 class="category-list-item__title">{{category.name}}({{ folder.articles_count }})</h3>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
         {% break %}
       {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly it. Thank you so much!